# I can't seem to be able install PANDAS on CMD

Tags: python, installation, pip

First I got this message:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable.**
```

Then I got this error:

```
ERROR: Exception:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Marshal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 438, in _error_catcher
        yield
      File "C:\Users\Marshal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 519, in read
        data = self._fp.read(amt) if not fp_closed else b""
      File "C:\Users\Marshal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\filewrapper.py", line 62, in read
        data = self.__fp.read(amt)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 454, in read
        n = self.readinto(b)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 498, in readinto
        n = self.fp.readinto(b)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\socket.py", line 669, in readinto
        return self._sock.recv_into(b)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1241, in recv_into
        return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1099, in read
        return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
    socket.timeout: The read operation timed out
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Marshal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 173, in _main
        status = self.run(options, args)
      File "C:\Users\Marshal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 203, in wrapper
        return func(self, options, args)
      File "C:\Users\Marshal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 315, in run
        requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
      File "C:\Users\Marshal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\resolver.py", line 94, in resolve
        result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
      File "C:\Users\Marshal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 472, in resolve
        state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
      File "C:\Users\Marshal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 341, in resolve
        self._add_to_criteria(self.state.criteria, r, parent=None)
      File "C:\Users\Marshal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 172, in _add_to_criteria
        if not criterion.candidates:
      File "C:\Users\Marshal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\structs.py", line 151, in __bool__
        return bool(self._sequence)
      File "C:\Users\Marshal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 140, in __bool__
        return any(self)
      File "C:\Users\Marshal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 128, in <genexpr>
        return (c for c in iterator if id(c) not in self._incompatible_ids)
      File "C:\Users\Marshal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 32, in _iter_built
        candidate = func()
      File "C:\Users\Marshal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\factory.py", line 204, in _make_candidate_from_link
        self._link_candidate_cache[link] = LinkCandidate(
      File "C:\Users\Marshal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 295, in __init__
        super().__init__(
      File "C:\Users\Marshal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 156, in __init__
        self.dist = self._prepare()
      File "C:\Users\Marshal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 227, in _prepare
        dist = self._prepare_distribution()
      File "C:\Users\Marshal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 305, in _prepare_distribution
        return self._factory.preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(
      File "C:\Users\Marshal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 508, in prepare_linked_requirement
        return self._prepare_linked_requirement(req, parallel_builds)
      File "C:\Users\Marshal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 550, in _prepare_linked_requirement
        local_file = unpack_url(
      File "C:\Users\Marshal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 239, in unpack_url
        file = get_http_url(
      File "C:\Users\Marshal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 102, in get_http_url
        from_path, content_type = download(link, temp_dir.path)
      File "C:\Users\Marshal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\download.py", line 145, in __call__
        for chunk in chunks:
      File "C:\Users\Marshal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\progress_bars.py", line 144, in iter
        for x in it:
      File "C:\Users\Marshal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\utils.py", line 63, in response_chunks
        for chunk in response.raw.stream(
      File "C:\Users\Marshal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 576, in stream
        data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
      File "C:\Users\Marshal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 541, in read
        raise IncompleteRead(self._fp_bytes_read, self.length_remaining)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "C:\Users\Marshal\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 443, in _error_catcher
        raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, "Read timed out.")
    pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out.
```

Comment: This message *Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable* is because you installed Python "for all users" which requires elevated permissions, but you are now asking `pip` to write to `site-packages` from a console session with user privileges. Run `cmd` as Administrator and the warning will go away.

Comment: The second error seems to be indicating a network problem.